# Ambiguous type variable in let binding

Tags: haskell, types

I am new to Haskell from a C++ and Java background. Occassionally, I have trouble with Haskell's type system. My current error is with this piece of code:

```
countIf :: (Integral b) => [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> b
countIf [] p = 0
countIf (x:xs) p
  | p x = 1 + countIf xs p
  | otherwise = countIf xs p

isRelativelyPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
isRelativelyPrime m n = gcd m n == 1

phi :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b
phi n = countIf [1..(n - 1)] (isRelativelyPrime n)

main = print [(n, phi n, ratio) | n <- [1..10], let ratio = (fromIntegral (phi n)) / n]
```

The error message is

```
prog.hs:13:60:
    Ambiguous type variable `b' in the constraints:
      `Fractional b' arising from a use of `/' at prog.hs:13:60-85
      `Integral b' arising from a use of `phi' at prog.hs:13:75-79
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

13:60 is just before the usage of fromIntegral in the let binding in my list comprehension in main. I'm still trying to get used to ghc's error messages. I am unable to decipher this particular one in order to figure out what I need to change to get my code to compile. Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `countIf` may be defined as combination of standard functions: `countIf = length . flip filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call fromIntegral on n as well since Haskell doesn't automatically convert from integral types, which you already seem to know since you called fromIntegral (phi n). I make this mistake all the time, not a big deal!

Comment: Thanks, that is the detail that I was missing.

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of a common beginner mistake: *excessively polymorphic code*.

You've made your code as general as possible, e.g.

```
phi :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

this will take *any* integral type to any other integral type, via the `phi` transformation.

Such polymorphic code is great for libraries, but not so great for type inference. I'd put money that you just want this to work on Integers, so we can go ahead an give a more accurate type,

```
countIf :: [Integer] -> (Integer -> Bool) -> Integer
countIf [] p = 0
countIf (x:xs) p
  | p x       = 1 + countIf xs p
  | otherwise = countIf xs p

isRelativelyPrime :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
isRelativelyPrime m n = gcd m n == 1

phi :: Integer -> Integer
phi n = countIf [1..(n - 1)] (isRelativelyPrime n)

main = print [ (n, phi n, ratio)
             | n <- [1..10], let ratio = (fromIntegral (phi n)) ]
```

and the type error just goes away.

You may even see performance improvements (particularly if you specialize to `Int`).

Comment: I'm personally against recommending `Int` to newbies, but +1 for recognising excessive polymorphism as a problem :)

Comment: @DonStewart Thanks for the tip on excessive polymorphism. I probably do go overboard with that at this point. However, the error does NOT disappear with that change. Your code does not have the division in "let ratio = ..." binding (thus the name "ratio") which is where the error message occurred. Max's answer above solved the error since I needed a "fromInteger n" in order to do the floating-point division.

Comment: @benmachine Why are you against recommending Int's for newbies?

Comment: @Code-Guru: because the only advantage over `Integer` is performance, which newbies typically don't worry about so much; the disadvantage is causing subtle overflow bugs, which I think of as very un-Haskelly.

Comment: @benmachine Thanks! I will keep that in mind. p.s. I'm no newbie to programming in general, just to Haskell and functional programming. ;-)